# Using spring jdbc template to query for list of parameters

Tags: spring, jdbc

New to Spring JDBC template but I'm wondering if I am able to pass a list of parameters and execute query once for each parameter in list. As I've seen many examples, the list of parameters being passed is for the execution of the query using all the parameters provided. Rather I am trying to execute query multiple times and for each time using new parameter in list.

For example:
Let's say I have a List of Ids - params (Strings)

```
List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
params.add("1234");
params.add("2345");
```

trying to do something like:

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, params, new CustomResultSetExtractor());
```

which I know as per documentation is not allowed. I mean for one it has to be an array. I've seen simple examples where query is something like `"select * from employee where id = ?"` and they are passing `new Object[]{"1234"}` into method. And I'm trying to avoid the IN() condition. In my case each id will return multiple rows which is why I'm using ResultSetExtractor.

I know one option would be to iterate over list and include each id in list as a parameter, something like:

```
for(String id : params){
  getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[]{id}, new CustomResultSetExtractor());
}
```

Just want to know if I can do this some other way. Sorry, I Should mention that I am trying to do a Select. Originally was hoping to return a List of custom objects for each resultset.

Comment: maybe you can use a preparedStatement and loop your ids to set the parameters, this can also save your memory and time.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to pass an array of params for the API, but you may also assume that your first param is an array. I believe this should work:

```
String sql = "select * from employee where id in (:ids)"; // or should there be '?'
getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[]{params}, new CustomResultSetExtractor());
```

Or you could explicitly specify, that the parameter is an array

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[]{params}, new int[]{java.sql.Types.ARRAY}, new CustomResultSetExtractor());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preparedStatement and do batch job:

eg. from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

```
public int[] batchUpdate(final List<Actor> actors) {
        int[] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("update t_actor set first_name = ?, " +
                "last_name = ? where id = ?",
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                        ps.setString(1, actors.get(i).getFirstName());
                        ps.setString(2, actors.get(i).getLastName());
                        ps.setLong(3, actors.get(i).getId().longValue());
                    }

                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return actors.size();
                    }
                });
        return updateCounts;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to use the in clause, but I think its the best solution for your problem.

If you use a for in this way, I think it's not optimal.

```
for(String id : params){
  getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[]{id}, new CustomResultSetExtractor());
}
```

I think it's a better solution to use the in clause. And then use a ResultSetExtractor to iterate over the result data. Your extractor can return a Map instead of a List, actually a Map of List.

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>
```

Here there is a simple tutorial explaining its use

http://pure-essence.net/2011/03/16/how-to-execute-in-sql-in-spring-jdbctemplate/

Comment: ok, I will probably go with IN clause... wasn't too sure, as I may have in the tens of thousands of ids.

Comment: OK, I think you can use pagination over the IDs and make the queries with  500 IDs at time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution:

```
public List<TestUser> findUserByIds(int[] ids) {
  String[] s = new String[ids.length];
  Arrays.fill(s, "?");
  String sql = StringUtils.join(s, ',');

  return jdbcTemplate.query(String.format("select * from users where id in (%s)", sql),
    ArrayUtils.toObject(ids), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(TestUser.class));
}
```

this one maybe what you want. `BeanPropertyRowMapper` is just for example, it will be very slow when there's a lot of records. you should change it to another more efficient RowMapper.